# A question about for-loop condition in java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am working on the problem below:
Given a non-empty array of digits representing a non-negative integer, plus one to the integer.
Eg:[1,2,3] Output:[1,2,4]
My approach is usring carry to calculate the singular digit from end to start.
I got 2 version of this problem. First one does not work when the input is [1,4,4,9].However, the second one is wokring. In the second version, I change the for-loop condition. I wonder why this happened? Could anyone help me with this? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!
Version 1:

```
   public static int[] plusOne(int[] digits) {
        int sum = 0;
        int len = digits.length;
        int carry = (digits[digits.length -1]+1)/10;
        digits[digits.length -1] = (digits[digits.length -1]+1)%10;

        for (int j = len-2;j >= 0;j--){

            carry = (digits[j]+carry)/10 ;
            digits[j] =(digits[j]+carry)%10 ;
        }

        if (carry==0) return digits;
        else{
            int[] res = new int[len+1];
            res[0] = 1;
            int i = 0;
            for (int j=1;j<res.length;j++){
                res[j] = digits [i++];
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
```

Version 2:

```
public static int[] plusOne(int[] digits) {
        int sum = 0;
        int len = digits.length;
        int carry = (digits[digits.length -1]+1)/10;
        digits[digits.length -1] = (digits[digits.length -1]+1)%10;

        for (int j = len-2;j >= 0;j--){
        int temp = digits[j]+carry;
        carry = (temp)/10 ;
        digits[j] =(temp)%10 ;
        }

        if (carry==0) return digits;
        else{
            int[] res = new int[len+1];
            res[0] = 1;
            int i = 0;
            for (int j=1;j<res.length;j++){
                res[j] = digits [i++];
            }
            return res;
        }
```

Comment: There is no change in any condition. The only difference is that you used a `temp` variable in example 2. Example 1 doesn't work because you're calculating `digits[j] =(digits[j]+carry)%10 ;` where `carry` has already been changed in the previous line.

Comment: In your first solution the value of `carry` has changed in the expression `digits[j] =(digits[j]+carry)%10;` in the row before. In the second example you have assigned the calculation to a `temp` variable in the loop.

Comment: QBrute basicly answered the question. Next time I'd suggest you to use a debugger - it is really useful tool in situations like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Posting a longer answer after all...</sub>

The only difference in those two code snippets are the first `for` loops. Your first example doesn't work as you expected.

```
for (int j = len-2;j >= 0;j--){
        carry = (digits[j]+carry)/10 ;
        digits[j] =(digits[j]+carry)%10 ;
}
```

Here the problem lies in the line `carry = (digits[j]+carry)/10 ;`
You're changing the variable `carry`, but this value is being used in the next line.

Let's say, `carry` was `1` and `digits[j]` is `5`. After `carry = (digits[j]+carry)/10;` the variable `carry` changed to `0` and the subsequent calculation of `digits[j]` results in `5` instead of `6`.

The second example works, because you're introducing an intermediate variable `temp`:

```
for (int j = len-2;j >= 0;j--){
    int temp = digits[j]+carry;
    carry = (temp)/10 ;
    digits[j] =(temp)%10 ;
}
```

`temp` is calculated once and then only read from, so `carry` and `digits` are not dependant on each other any more. In turn, you will get the result you expect.